# Can I use continue and break in Javascript for...in and for...of loops?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, for-in-loop, for-of-loop

Can I use the `break` and `continue` statements inside the `for...in` and `for...of` type of loops? Or are they only accessible inside regular `for` loops.

Example:

```
myObject = { 
  propA: 'foo', 
  propB: 'bar'
};

for (let propName in myObject) {
  if (propName !== 'propA') {
    continue;
  }
  else if (propName === 'propA') {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes? Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? Add a debugger or console log inside the conditions

Comment: @Persijn lack of research. It's *too* simple - just running the code already present with a minor alteration (add a log statement) reveals the answer. Not to mention the *thousands* of other resources online. If the question was "can I use a different name than `propName` in my code", would you still say it's a good question?

Comment: @Persijn Thanks. I was wondering the same thing. Two close votes on "unclear what you're asking for". How can this question not be clear? I know I could test this myself. But before testing, I searched on StackOverflow trying to find the answer. And I couldn't find one. So I asked!

Comment: @Persijn It's not about simplicity. A user with 125+ questions asking "*Debug this for me*" when they can easily do it themselves

Comment: I see the question as good, since I can see other users searching for this. And i can see value in having this question on stackoverflow even if its possible to find the answer other places.

Comment: @Persijn that's a fair point.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yep - works in all loops.

```js
const myObject = { 
  propA: 'foo', 
  propB: 'bar'
};

for (let propName in myObject) {
  console.log(propName);
  if (propName !== 'propA') {
    continue;
  }
  else if (propName === 'propA') {
    break;
  }
}
```

(By loops I mean `for`, `for...in`, `for...of`, `while` and `do...while`, *not* `forEach`, which is actually a function defined on the Array prototype.)

Comment: There probably is a way to get the same behavior in forEach. That could be another good question.

Comment: I would argue that `forEach` is not really a loop, but a function with a callback argument. Also, `break` is not restricted to loops but to all [blocks (MDN link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), which is a difference it has with `continue`

Comment: Not all blocks - just loops and switches.

Comment: ... and labelled blocks.

Comment: Oh yes, those too @Teemu.

Comment: @Persijn there are already questions about `break` and `continue` in `forEach`...

Comment: In `forEach` you can use `return` if a condition is not met. Though it's not very idiomatic.